# Rebranding of a Flutter Project

Tags: android, ios, flutter, command-line, branding

I need to rename my current project fast( rename bundleID, change icon, etc) and need to write some little tool which i can use with command line to affect changes in my project files and folders. What is the best way to do it with Dart?
Is there some example of such similar command line tool?
The aim is to sell my product to different clients with their own corporate identity.